# java heap space

Tags: jakarta-ee

when i execute my programm which contain 2 loops one nested in the other,i obtain this error OutOfMemoryError java heap space.i 've been looking for solution for a week but no result.i know that may problem is in creating instances i my loops so it takes a lot of memory.son that cause memmory leak.i tried increasing memory size but this is not  enough. my question is how can i develop the same program without using a lot of memory in the excution.this is my programm.

```
public String getAllActionsJson(){
        //liste des actions de la table action
        List<Action> actions = actionService.getAllActions();
        //liste onglets de la table typeAction
        List<TypeAction> typesActions=actionService.getTypeActions();
        ActionNoeudJson actionRacine = null;
        ActionNoeudJson actionFeuille = null;
        List<ActionNoeudJson> listeFilles = null;
        for(int i=0;i<typesActions.size();i++)
        {
            listeFilles = new ArrayList<ActionNoeudJson>();
            actionRacine=new ActionNoeudJson();
            actionRacine.setId(typesActions.get(i).getId());
            actionRacine.setText(typesActions.get(i).getLibelle());
            for(int j=0;j<actions.size();j++)
            {
                //si le type de l'action est le meme que le type de l'onglet
                //on affecte actionFeuille à la racine courante(onglet approprié) 
                if(typesActions.get(i).getId()==actions.get(j).getTypeAction().getId())
                {   
                    actionFeuille = new ActionNoeudJson();
                    actionFeuille.setId(actions.get(j).getId());
                    actionFeuille.setText(actions.get(j).getLibelle());
                    actionFeuille.setIconCls("icon-tip");
                    listeFilles.add(actionFeuille);
                    actionRacine.setChildren(listeFilles);
                }   
            }
            listeActions.add(actionRacine);

        }
        return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;

    }
```

Comment: You probably have a memory leak. I would try setting your reused variables to null after use in your loops. I'm not sure if that is your problem but it's worth a try. try googling `how to fix a java memory leak`

Comment: i've googled that for a week and the only given solution is increasing memory size with the command -Xmx512m in run configurations but that treat only the symptom not the the disease which is in this algorithm i'm sharing in my question

Comment: https://www.google.ca/search?q=how+to+debug+a+java+memory+leak&aq=f&oq=how+to+debug+a+java+memory+leak&aqs=chrome.0.57j0j62l3.15404&sugexp=chrome,mod=12&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

This is the area of study of a subject called Algorithm Analysis. If you are not familiar with  [Big O Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) at least, it will be very hard for you to understand how to improve your algorithm.

If you do understand that notation and can do basic analysis, then try to find out what part of the code is using the most amount of memory, and try to optimize that first. For example, maybe there's data that you are carrying around which you don't really need for that computation.

It seems that you are trying to set some values for all actions for all types. How about doing it by chunks? try to split the work so that you don't have everything in memory at the same time. Then gradually build a flat array of actions, then do a single for to listeActions.add() every element in the array.